# Simple example of MultiSelectionModel

Tags: gwt, gwt-2.2-celltable, cellbrowser

I'm trying to make CellBrowser capable of multi-selection. I just start learning this new concept of cells in GWT 2.2 and I'm look at example that Google has in its [GWT Showcase](http://gwt.google.com/samples/Showcase/Showcase.html#!CwCellBrowser) but their code is not very clear. Where can I find a same example but easier to read.

Comment: What do you find unclear in the showcase code? And what do you want to know exactly about CellBrowser and MultiSelectionModel?